# setting horizantal scroll bar of text box in compact framework 2.0 using c#

Tags: c#, compact-framework

i'm new in c# language. i need a help for this problem.

i have a text box for this i have set up horizantol scroll bar. i know that for this i have to do wordwrap property false. i have done it but it not showing scroll bar.
i'm doing all these things in compact framework 2.0 using c#. its only showing the vertical scroll bar all the time.

pls help me .

Answer (score 1):

You also have to set the `Multiline` property to `true`, then it should work.